# How to change the position in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a section with list of div's with image and content, i want to interchange the position of image and content, i can do it for static content, but i am pulling the data from mysql table.

**For example**

```
Section 1
Left side - Image  | Right side Content
Section 2
Left side - Content | Right side Image 
Section 3
Left side - Image  | Right side Content
Section 4
Left side - Content | Right side Image 

<div class="section">
  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 1 </p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 2 </p></div>
    <div> <img src="./img/2.jpg"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 3 </p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 4 </p></div>
    <div> <img src="./img/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Above section is dynamic looped from the mysql table

**Gallery**

```
id    content       img
1      cxxxx        img1
2      cxxxx        img2
3      cxxxx        img3
4      cxxxx        img1
```

Comment: Your `p` tag is not closed. Did you ever hear about css `order` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order You can also make it with a `display:grid`

Comment: @MaxiGui — The end tag for the `p` element is optional. There was no need for it to have been added in to the above code.

Comment: @Quentin pretty sure IE would proove you wrong... And you still have specialy in large companies.

Comment: @MaxiGui — Even IE doesn't have any problems implementing that part of HTML. The end tag for `p` elements has been optional since `p` elements were first introduced in the original version of HTML: http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 examples, the first with `order` and a second even more simple  with `column-reverse`. Where we are targeting every odd `.service`:

```css
.section > .service:nth-child(odd){
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section > .service:nth-child(odd) > div:first-child{
  order: 2;
}
.section > .service:nth-child(odd) > div:last-child{
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 2</div>
    <div> <img src="./img/2.jpg"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 4</div>
    <div> <img src="./img/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Example 2 only with `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;`:

```css
.section > .service:nth-child(odd){
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 2</div>
    <div> <img src="./img/2.jpg"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
   <div> <img src="./img/3.jpg"></div>
   <div> <p> Content 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="service">
    <div> <p> Content 4</div>
    <div> <img src="./img/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```